# Interpretation of coefficients in logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, coefficients, interpretation

I know there are answers to similar questions but I cannot understand exactly how to interpret the coefficients estimates in logistic regression.

I am trying to predict if the probability of having a certain disease is influenced by two variables: `sex` and being a `veteran`. (there are many more variables that I am considering but for the sake of simplicity I just mentioned these two)

I have this result:

```
Coefficients:
                          Estimate  Std. Error  z value   Pr(>|z|) 
(Intercept)               16.46555   7.73733    2.128    0.033332 *
is.Female                 0.37127    0.07204    5.154    2.55e-07 ***
is.Veteran                -0.43195   0.13957    -3.095   0.001970 **
```

I want to claim how sex influences having the disease.

Can I say that being a `female` makes the probability of having the disease `0.37` times higher than if the patient was a `man`?

Comment: Maybe this question is for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: bbiasi might be right that Cross Validated is a good place for questions like this, but either way you will need to give a bit more information on your model. Likely your coefficients are in term of log-odds https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-how-do-i-interpret-odds-ratios-in-logistic-regression/ You will be able to get more helpful feedback if you can include data and code so that others can help you figure out exactly what your model output means.

Comment: In addition to probably wanting to exponentiate if you want an interpretation similar  to above, you'll want to think about what's going on with other variables. Without knowing your questions, I'd want to include an interaction term between gender or sex and veteran status. The intercept in your model will be for the reference category, which I guess is male non-veteran here...

Comment: Thank you all! I have used the glm function in r, I don't know if it expresses results in terms of log

Answer (score 0):

You are fitting a logistic regression, so you can't interpret the regression coefficient directly. You can calculate the odds ratio (OR) with regression coefficient.
In this case,

> OR=exp(0.37)=1.45

This means that given the `veteran` status, `risk of female = 1.45 * risk of male`.